# Cytoscape 3.8.0 launches with errors and R package RCy3 not working with it

Tags: java, r, cytoscape

when I launch Cytoscape 3.8.0, i see following error message [image: Cytoscape 3.8.0 error]

Then I looked into the task history and I see many errors as shown below,

```
 couldn't find resource 'groupSettings.props' in jar.
 couldn't find resource 'layout.grid.props' in jar.
 couldn't find resource 'layout.hierarchical.props' in jar.
 couldn't find resource 'layout.circular.props' in jar.
 couldn't find resource 'layout.stacked-node-layout.props' in jar.
 couldn't find resource 'layout.attribute-circle.props' in jar.
 couldn't find resource 'layout.degree-circle.props' in jar.
 couldn't find resource 'layout.attributes-layout.props' in jar.
 couldn't find resource 'layout.kamada-kawai.props' in jar.
 couldn't find resource 'layout.fruchterman-rheingold.props' in jar.
 couldn't find resource 'layout.cose.props' in jar.
 couldn't find resource 'layout.isom.props' in jar.
 couldn't find resource 'layout.force-directed.props' in jar.
 couldn't find resource 'stringApp.props' in jar.
 couldn't find resource 'enrichmentmap.props' in jar.
 couldn't find resource 'layout.genemania-force-directed.props' in jar.
```

When I run `RCy3::cytoscapePing()` in R console, I see the following error

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Failed to connect to localhost port 1234: Connection refused
```

However, Cytoscape 3.7.x launches smoothly and `RCy3::cytoscapePing()` produces `[1] "You are connected to Cytoscape!"`. RCy3 version is 2.4.6.
To me, it looks like a java error as Cytoscape 3.8.0 uses java11  and Cytoscape 3.7.x uses java 1.8. How to fix this error?

`whereis -b java` produces
`java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/share/java /opt/jdk1.8.0_73/bin/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8/bin/java` . java11 is clearly on the path.

`update-alternatives --config java` shows that the java11 is selected as default java.

```
  Selection        Path                                     Priority   Status
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java    1081      auto mode
     1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java    1081      manual mode
   * 2            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8/bin/java           1         manual mode
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error message, you need to restart Cytoscape when that dialog pops up.  Until you do, Cytoscape won't be listening on port 1234.  Once you restart and that dialog no longer pops up, things should be fine.

Comment: I should mention that if you switch back to Cytoscape 3.7.2, you will need to restart again.  Essentially, switching versions takes two starts of Cytoscape to allow CyREST to reset.

Comment: the error is not that trivial! it comes back again after restart, sometimes works though. moreover, CyREST works all the time with Cytoscape 3.7.x but erratically with 3.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Open Cytoscape App, restart R, load `library(RCy3); library(phytools); library(ape);`  and add
`options("cyRestApi"="http://localhost:1234")`
and check that everything is right with
`cytoscapePing ()` the output should be *You are connected to Cytoscape!*